# Variable scope in perl

Tags: perl, variables, cgi, global

I am using CGI in strict mode and a bit confused with variables. I am reading a file that has two lines. Storing both in two variables. But when i try outputing them using html, it says global variable error

This is what I am doing

```
 open TEXT, "filename";
 $title = <TEXT>;
 $about = <TEXT>; 
 close TEXT;
```

but this gives the global variable error. whats the best way to fix this?

Comment: There is no error that says "global variable error". Never, ever give approximate error messages -- always give the *exact* message as given.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare variable with `my` to make its scope local. This is the best practice and compulsory when using `strict`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'filename' or die $!;
my ( $title, $about ) = <$fh>;
close $fh;
```

Further improvements:

1. Avoided bareword file handles (e.g. `FILE`). Instead use local file handles such as `my $fh`
2. Used error handling with `die` when dealing with file processing
3. Combined assignment of `$title` and `$about` as suggested by *@Suic*
4. `use warnings` to display what's going wrong as pointed out by *@TLP*

Comment: I tried that as well, but when i try accessing it in the html section below, it doesnt show up.

Comment: print <<END HTML       <p>$title</p> END_HTML;

Comment: `use warnings` will show you the way.

Comment: I have to use the pre formated way of showing it on a page. Its a requirement.

Comment: Tried that as well, Im not getting any errors or warning but its simply not outputing anything on the screen. so im guessing there is an issue with reading the file

Comment: @user2055171 In that case, did you use `die`? Did you try executing cgi in terminal? what's the output?

Comment: I tried that as well. No output at all, just for the reading file part. If i output the filename (stored in variable) it prints it. But just nothing for the part thats read from the file.

Comment: @user2055171 Sorry to say, in that case, I can't comment anything without seeing code. In-fact nobody will be able to debug what you're doing wrong, just in AIR. `no output at all`?? There can be hundred ways things can go wrong. I may sound rude but you have gone far beyond original question. You need to debug and post another relevant question.